# Is there a window or portable AC system I can use with an hopper window without removing window?

Tags: air-conditioning, air, portable-ac

I'm trying to see if it's possible to install a portable AC with hose in this dorm room hopper window without removing the window (See picture attached). I can't seem to find anything online nor a kit for such window. Any ideas? Is it possible? All comments appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

[image: Hopper Window, Opens Inward]

Answer (score 2):

There are portable AC units that stand on the floor and vent through  window. See photo below. You would have to be creative with the window you have, and block part of it with Styrofoam sheeting or clear plastic sheeting, drop cloth. Then install your vent duct and that would depend on the type included with your unit. If it gets hot enough, that will peak your ingenuity. You're in school, use those brains. :-)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have removed the window by taking the upper arms out then lifting 1 side so the pins come out of the track. Set the window aside and use a piece of acrylic or poly carbonate. To block the hole and put the vent line(s)  in the plastic.

This is the only method I have found that customers were ok with and the window can be put back in in just a couple of minutes. Out of 5 people in the same frat one was ok with 1/2” plywood (it was cheaper / the others wanted clear)

There are not many options as the window blocks the opening so temporary removal ended up as the only real option that was in any way secure and looked acceptable. One window the glass was broken so I set polycarbonate in the frame and reglazed it other than the hole it looked good and I am not sure if they ever replaced the glass.